# AngularJS Cordova app sometimes cannot find controller

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-controller, ng-controller

I have this weird error in a Cordova/AngularJS app.

Sometimes (rarely) AngularJS cannot find the controller and chrashes, leaving users with a half-loaded unresponsive view.

The error only seems to happen when the phone has been locked for some time and is next to impossible for me to recreate at a regular basis. It just happens sometimes.

When the user close the app and restart it everything works fine again.

Thus far I have only received complaints about this error for Android devices and not for iOS devices.

EDIT: I have also now seen the error on iOS devices.

I really hope someone is able to shed light on this issue.

---

My index.html looks like this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="guideApp">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.6/mapbox.js http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js;">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/snap.css" />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/mapbox.css' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/guideapp.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/xpengineicons.css" />
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/guideappTest.css" />-->
 
  <title></title>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png"/>

  <meta name="application-name" content="GuideApp"/>
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/favicons/mstile-144x144.png" />
  <meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="img/favicons/mstile-70x70.png" />
  <meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="img/favicons/mstile-150x150.png" />
  <meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="img/favicons/mstile-310x150.png" />
  <meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="img/favicons/mstile-310x310.png" />
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="globalCtrl" data-snap-ignore="true">
  <div class="snap-drawers">
   <div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-left sideMenu">
    <a href="#" ng-click="goTo('/home')">{{::langPack.startPage[lang]}}</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="goTo('/tourSelect')">{{::langPack.selectTour[lang]}}</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="goTo('/map')">{{::langPack.map[lang]}}</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="goTo('/news')">{{::langPack.news[lang]}}</a>
    
    <a href="#" ng-click="toggleFoto($event)" class="fotoToggle" ng-class="{'redFotoToggle': photosInUploadQue > 0}">{{::langPack.photoMenu[lang]}}<i class="icon-angle-down fotoToggleAngle"></i></a>
    <div class="fotoMenu" id="fotoMenu">
     <a href="#" ng-click="toggleUploadPopup()" class="noUploadMenuItem" ng-class="{'uploadMenuItem': photosInUploadQue > 0}" compile="langPack.uploadPhotos[lang]"></a>
     <a href="#" ng-click="goTo('/commonTours')">{{::langPack.followAnothersTour[lang]}}</a>
     <a href="#" ng-click="broadcastResetPhotoTour();">{{::langPack.endPhototour[lang]}}</a>
     <a href="#" ng-click="goTo('/viewtours')">{{::langPack.seePreviousTour[lang]}}</a>

     <!--<a href="#" ng-click="selectPicture();">{{::langPack.photoFromGallery[lang]}}</a>-->
     <a href="#" ng-click="broadcastSelectPicture();">{{::langPack.selectFromGallery[lang]}}</a>
     <!--<a href="#" ng-if="actionRadius>100" ng-click="broadcastToggleActionRadius();">[Smaller radius]</a>-->
     <!--<a href="#" ng-if="actionRadius<100" ng-click="broadcastToggleActionRadius();">[Larger radius]</a>-->
     <!--<a href="#" ng-click="broadcastToggleActionRadius();">[{{langPack.toggleActionRadius[lang]}}]</a>-->
     <!--<a href="#" ng-click="goTo('/end')">[End waypoint tour]</a> -->
    </div>

    <a href="#" ng-click="goTo('/about')">{{::langPack.about[lang]}}</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="sync.checkUpdates();">
     {{::langPack.sync[lang]}}
     <span id="updateCheck" class="updateCheck"><div class="circle"></div>{{::langPack.checkForUpdates[lang]}}</span>
     <span id="uptodate" class="updateCheck uptodate"><i class="icon-ok"></i>{{::langPack.upToDate[lang]}}</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="showIntroOverlay()">{{::langPack.showIntroOverlay[lang]}}</a>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="content" class="snap-content content" ng-style="customBg">
   <nav id="header" ng-controller="cameraCtrl">
    <a href="" ng-click="toggleMenu()" class="menuBtn show" id="menuBtn"><img src="img/menu-regular.svg"><!--<div class="menuNotification" ng-if="photosInUploadQue > 0">{{photosInUploadQue}}</div>--></a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="goTo(backDirection)" class="backBtn" id="backBtn"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></a>
    <h1></h1>

    <img ng-src="{{customLogo}}" id="logo">
    <!-- Kamera når det virker -->
    <a href="#" ng-click="takeGuidePicture()" class="cameraBtn" ng-if="showCam === true"><i class="icon-camera"></i></a>  
    <!-- <a href="#" ng-click="selectPicture()" class="galleryPhotoBtn" ng-if="showCam === true"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>   -->

    <!-- <a href="#" ng-click="openUploadPopup($event)" id="photoUpload" class="uploadBtn"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></a> -->

    <!-- <a onclick = "window.open('http://guideapp.tmts.dk/', '_blank', 'location=yes'); return false;" id="viewInBrowser" class="uploadBtn"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a> -->
    
    <div id="uploadPopupOverlay" class="popupOverlay" ng-click="closeUploadPopup();"></div>
  
    <section id="uploadPopup">
     <p>{{::langPack.uploadAndShare[lang]}}</p>
     <form novalidate ng-submit="uploadPhotosSubmittedByPopup($event)">
      <label for="emailInput" ng-show="showEmail === true">
       {{::langPack.yourEmail[lang]}}
       <div class="error" ng-if="emailMsg">{{::emailMsg}}</div>
      </label>
      <input type="email" value="{{emailAdress}}" required name="emailInput" ng-model="emailAdress" ng-show="showEmail === true" id="emailAdress">
      
      <label for="titleInput">
       {{::langPack.yourTitel[lang]}}
       <div class="error" ng-if="titleMsg">{{::titleMsg}}</div>
      </label>
      <input type="text" value="{{tourTitle}}" name="titleInput" ng-model="tourTitle" id="uploadTitle" required>
      
      <p class="emailExists" ng-show="showEmail === false"><span compile="langPack.sendTo[lang]"></span> <a href="#" ng-click="editEmail($event)">[{{::langPack.editEmail[lang]}}]</a></p>
      
      <button class="btn left" ng-click="closeUploadPopup();">{{::langPack.cancel[lang]}}</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn right">{{::langPack.ok[lang]}}</button>
     </form>
    </section>
   </nav>
   
   <div class="slideInLeft" ng-view></div>
  </div>
  <aside ng-class="{active: showIntro}" id="intro" ng-swipe-left="nextSlide()" class="" ng-swipe-right="prevSlide()">
   <div>
    <div id="introSwipe">
     <section id="intro{{$index+1}}" class="introSlide" ng-class="{'active': $index === 0}" ng-repeat="slide in introSlides" style="background-image: url('{{slide}}')"></section>
    </div>
    <section id="noShow">
     <div class="slideNavigation">
      <button ng-click="prevSlide()" ng-class="{disabled: firstSlide}">{{::langPack.prevSlide[lang]}}</button>
      <div class="slideProgress">{{slideProgress}}/{{introSlides.length}}</div>
      <button ng-click="nextSlide()" ng-class="{disabled: lastSlide}">{{::langPack.nextSlide[lang]}}</button>
     </div>
    </section>
   </div>
   <a id="closeIntro" href="#" ng-click="toggleIntro(); $event.preventDefault()">{{::langPack.toggleIntroText[lang]}}</a>
  </aside>

  <section id="confirmOverlay" class="popupOverlay" ng-click="confirmValue = false;">
   <section class="checkPopup confirmPopup" id="confirmPopup">
    <p id="confirmMessage"></p>

    <button class="btn right" ng-click="confirmValue = true;">{{::langPack.ok[lang]}}</button>
    <button class="btn left" ng-click="confirmValue = false;">{{::langPack.cancel[lang]}}</button>
   </section>
  </section>

  <section id="spinnerOverlay" class="popupOverlay">
   <section class="checkPopup spinnerPopup" id="spinnerPopup">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="spinnerText" id="spinnerText"></div>
   </section>
  </section>

  <section id="statusOverlay" class="popupOverlay" ng-click="status.hide()">
   <section class="checkPopup statusPopup" id="statusPopup">
    <p id="statusText"></p>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="status.hide()">Ok</button>
   </section>
  </section>

  <!-- JavaScript libraries -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular-locale_da-dk.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/snap.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="js/libs/md5.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular-listview.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Mapbox -->
  <!--<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.6/mapbox.js'></script>-->
  <!-- <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>  Draw GPX 20151014 -->

  <!-- leaflet -->
  <script src="js/libs/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src='js/libs/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>  <!-- Draw GPX 20151014 -->
  <script src='js/libs/leaflet-tilelayer-cordova.js'></script> <!-- Offline maps -->

  <!-- Custom script files -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

  <!-- included controllers -->
  <script src="controllers/globalCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/homeCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/aboutCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/tourSelectCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/mapCtrl.js"></script>

        <script src="controllers/cameraCtrl.js"></script> 
        <script src="controllers/viewtoursCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers/commonToursCtrl.js"></script>
        
        <script src="controllers/highscoreCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/downloadCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/waypointCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/waypointGalleryCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/endCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/newsCtrl.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

AngularJS is loaded with app.js:

```
// Init angular.js
var guideApp = angular.module('guideApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch']);

guideApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$compileProvider', function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    }).when('/home', {
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    }).when('/tourSelect', {
        controller: 'tourSelectCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/tourSelect.html'
    }).when('/map', {
        controller: 'mapCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/map.html'
    }).when('/about', {
        controller: 'aboutCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html' 
    }).when('/viewtours', {
        controller: 'viewtoursCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/viewtours.html'
    }).when('/commonTours', {
        controller: 'commonToursCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/commonTours.html'
    }).when('/highscore', {
        controller: 'highscoreCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/highscore.html'
    }).when('/download', {
        controller: 'downloadCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/download.html'
    }).when('/waypoint', {
        controller: 'waypointCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/waypoint.html'
    }).when('/waypointGallery', {
        controller: 'waypointGalleryCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/waypointGallery.html'
    }).when('/end', {
        controller: 'endCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/end.html'
    }).when('/news', {
        controller: 'newsCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/news.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|cdvfile|file):/);
}]);

guideApp.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
                // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
                return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {
                // when the 'compile' expression changes
                // assign it into the current DOM
                element.html(value);

                // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                // scope.
                // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
}])

// custom on touchstart directive
/*guideApp.directive('guideappTouchstart', [function () {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.on('touchstart', function (event) {
            scope.$apply(function () { 
                scope.$eval(attr.guideappTouchstart); 
            });
        });
    };
}]);*/
```

The index.js file looks like this:

```js
var http,
 app = {
 initialize: function () {
  this.bindEvents();
 },
 bindEvents: function () {
  if (!window.cordova) {
   this.onDeviceReady();
  } else {
   document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
  }
 },
 onDeviceReady: function () {
  app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
  console.log('Device ready');
  
  if (window.cordova) {
   // find and set the filesystem root
   window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
   window.requestFileSystem(1, 0, function (fileSystem) {
    console.log("got filesystem: "+fileSystem.name); // displays "persistent"
    //console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath); // displays "/"
    window.rootFS = fileSystem.root;
   });
  }
 },
 receivedEvent: function (id) {
  //angularInit();
  this.platform();
 },
 server: function (wwwroot) {
  if (httpd) {
   httpd.getURL(function (url) {
    if(url.length > 0) {
     document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = "server is up: <a href='" + url + "' target='_blank'>" + url + "</a>";
    } else {
     httpd.startServer({
      'www_root' : wwwroot,
      'port' : 8080
     }, function (url) {
      
      //updateStatus();
     }, function (error) {
      console.log('server error ', error);
     });
    }
    
   }, function () {});
  } else {
   console.log('CorHttpd plugin not available/ready');
  }
 },
 platform: function () {
  
  var deviceType;
  
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) { // Android
   
   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/i)) { // Android smartphone
    
    console.log('Android smartphone');
    
    deviceType = 'mobile';

   } else { // Android tablets

    //console.log('Android tablet');
    
    deviceType = 'tablet';

   }

  } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) { // IOS ipad
   
   //console.log('IOS tablet');
   
   deviceType = 'tablet';

  } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) { //IOS smartphone

   //console.log('IOS smartphone');
   
   deviceType = 'mobile';

  } else { // Dekstop as default

   //console.log('desktop');

   deviceType = 'tablet';

  }

 }
};

app.initialize();
```